# AWS Batch keep instances idle

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I'm using AWS Batch with `minvCpus = 0` and, as expected, it scales down EC2 instances immediately after the job queue is empty. I want instances to remain idle for 1 hour after executing the last job to avoid instance warmup overhead for the next jobs. Is there any parameter to control compute environment scaling behavior?

Comment: I dont think Batch gives you much/any control here.  I think you could set Scale-In protection on the instance - that would stop Batch terminating that instance - BUT you would need to set/remove that flag or the instance would never scale down. (You could perform this logic from a Lambda perhaps - maybe write a message to SQS at the end of Batch jobs to trigger the lambda)

Comment: yes, apparently there is no option to control the scale down behavior except Scale-In protection. thank you